# What do you call this old pipe to bath tap join and how do I remove it?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, bath

I'm trying to replace the bath taps. I'm at the point where i've removed one, but can't get the 2nd one off. They are connected differently (go figure).

See attached image:
[image: Problem join]

As i'm new to plumbing i don't know what type of join this is, and haven't been able to work it out, hence can't find out whether i should be able to just unscrew it.

I've tried using a wrench (and WD-40) but all i end up doing is twisting the pipe, which is curved. If i hold the pipe to stop it twisting i end up tilting the tap tail. It really seems like this join doesn't want to come off.

I've felt under the nut, and it seems like its a single piece from what i can tell, not sure if the extra thick piping below is part of it too??

My question is:

What type of joint is this? How can i undo it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a tap connector (obvious now I've found it), and you should be able to unscrew it. You can see [one here](http://www.toolstation.com/shop/Plumbing/Solder+Ring/SR+Straight+Tap+Connector+15mm+x+34/d20/sd2699/p41751)

It's the bottom nut you need to be turning. It's part of a joint that attaches the pipe to the tap.

Once you have this off you should be able to remove the tap as normal.

If it's stuck then something like WD40 or penetrating oil might help. Failing that *carefully* heating the nut with a heat gun might expand the various parts enough to loosen them. Take precautions to avoid getting direct heat onto the bath (it appears to be acrylic).

A more drastic approach would be to take a hacksaw to the thread to separate it that way.

Comment: Thanks for finding out the name! Is there anything I can do to loosen it? A more water pipe oriented wd40 type thing maybe? The nut is really stuck fast.

Comment: @George: I've used [Liquid Wrench](http://www.liquidwrench.com/) with good results on a lot of stuck nuts, you might give that a try (not sure if it's any different than WD40).

Comment: I like PB Blaster penetrating oil.  Also put some vice grips or wrench on the lower nut before you try to loosen the top one. it will probably take some force.  Heat will help, but Chris is right, be careful because the material looks like fiberglass or acrylic and could be damaged by excessive heat.

Answer (score 1):

You need a basin wrench.  See [this video](http://www.ehow.com/video_4971656_use-basin-wrench.html) for a description of how to use it.